# aiogram 3 builder

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram-3.x

Как собрать inline клавиатуру, чтоб последняя строка была в 2 кнопки

```
builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
row = []
for child in data.children:
    builder.button(
        text=f'text',
        callback_data=ChildCallbackFactory(id=child.id)
    )
    row.append(1)
row.append(2)
builder.adjust(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел как это сделать
Передать row через распаковку *row

```
builder.adjust(*row)
```